# How to trigger a Python or C# script to run when .Net/C# Windows service stops?

Tags: python, c#, .net, python-3.x

We have a c#/.net Windows service that parses big log files for us and updates a meta table when it does so. The problem is whenever you need to stop the service or (services, we have multiple of them running), one must manually delete the files that are in the process of being parsed in the local folder and also update the queue DB table where it tracks files to process.

I want to automate this. I am much more familiar with python so ideally, it would be a python script as opposed to .net. Is it possible to have a script that will trigger when the service is stopped? How would one do this?

I have tried doing this internally in the .net service but since it's multithreaded, files don't get cleaned up neatly. There's always a "can't stop service because another process is using it". It is like the service gets stuck trying to delete files when the Onstop() method is called. This was how I had tried to do it internally within the service:

```
protected override void OnStop()
        {
            ProducerConsumerQueue.Dispose();

            Logger.Info($"{ProducerConsumerQueue.Count()} logs will be canceled");

            CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            FileUtil.DeleteFilesInProgress(Constants.ODFS_STAGING);

            MetadataDbContext.UpdateServiceEntriesOnServiceReset();

            //look into some staging directory, delete all files. 

            Logger.Info($"{ProducerConsumerQueue.Count()} logs canceled");
        }


 public static void DeleteFilesInProgress(string directory)
        {
            var constantsutil = new ConstantsUtil();
            constantsutil.InitializeConfiguration();
            try
            {
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message);
                string subject = Constants.GENERAL_EMAIL_SUBJECT;
                string body = "The following error occured in Client.Util.ConstantsUtil:";
                string error = ex.ToString();  //ex.ToString makes it more verbose so you can trace it.
                var result = EmailUtil.Emailalert(subject, body, error);

            }
        }


public static int UpdateServiceEntriesOnServiceReset()
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;

            try
            {
                string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE {Constants.SERVICE_LOG_TBL} SET STATUS = '0'";

                    cmd.Connection = connection;

                    connection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error($"{ex.Message.ToString()}");
                string subject = Constants.GENERAL_EMAIL_SUBJECT;
                string body = "The following error occured in Client.MetadatDbContext while Parser was processing:";
                string error = ex.ToString();  //ex.ToString makes it more verbose so you can trace it.
                var result = EmailUtil.Emailalert(subject, body, error);
            }

            return rowsAffected;
        }
```

Comment: Either add the code to service or run something that will occasionally poll to see if service has ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script from `OnStop`:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("python yourscript.py"); 
// or whatever the command for executing your python script is on your system.
```

And then use something like `pywin32`'s `win32service` to find out the status of the service that launched the script, and then wait for it to die and release its hold on the files.

Then wipe them.

Comment: How do you make the python script wait for the service to die?

Comment: @edo101 I don't think `pywin32` gives much of an option. So you'll have to write your own: wait a bit, then check again, until the service is dead.